# Why not use/to use - difference

Tags: grammar

> Why not **to** use Magic Quotes.
>
> Why not use Magic Quotes.

What is the difference in meaning between these two ways of phrasing that sentence? To me  the first sentence sounds like it tells the reader that there are good reasons not to use Magic Quotes (a programming feature) and those reasons will be given. The second one sounds like a rhetorical question, something along the lines of "What the heck not? Let's use them!" Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in the way *not* affects the sentence due to the presence of the *to*.

> Why (not to use) Magic Quotes.
>
> (Why not) use Magic Quotes.

In the former, the *not* negates the *to use*, making the meaning an explanation of why using Magic Quotes is not something you want to do.

In the latter, the *not* negates the *why*, making the meaning a rhetorical question

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: @tchrist Apologies, my StackOverflow is leaking. I'll make sure to avoid it in future.